# aws elasticbeanstalk load balancer not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I have deleted and created a new Load Balancer to replace the existing one in my AWS BeanStalk Environement.
The whole configuration is exactly the same and it should work, except the previous entries has not all been updated.
It is looking for the old Load Balancer, so, i get an error message when deploying.

Do you know if there is any way to update this value without crashing all the BeanStalk Environment ? I can no find any place where i could do it.

[image: AWS BeanStalk Error]

Thank you for you help !

Romain

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue, this is how I addressed it:

- Change your EB environment from Load Balanced to Single Instance
- Ensure you have assigned more than 1 subnet to your instances in Configuration > Network
- Change back from single instance to Load Balanced

This should take a couple of minutes (less if you already have more than 1 subnet for your EB instances) but you might occur some downtime